# programming in c array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm reading Programming in C by Kochan, 3rd ed.

In the introduction to arrays (program 7.1) he gives an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int values[10];
    int index;

    values[0] = 197;
    values[2] = -100;
    values[5] = 350;
    values[3] = values[0] + values[5];
    values[9] =
    values[5] / 10;
    --values[2];

    for ( index = 0; index < 10; ++index )
        printf ("values[%i] = %i\n", index, values[index]);


    return 0;
}
```

which should give output

```
values[0] = 197
values[1] = 0
values[2] = -101
values[3] = 547
values[4] = 0
values[5] = 350
values[6] = 0
values[7] = 0
values[8] = 0
values[9] = 35
```

And with my quadriple-checking that i'm using the exact same code it only works halfway and gives me some weird extra numbers a [1], [4]

```
values[0] = 197
values[1] = 3210052
values[2] = -101
values[3] = 547
values[4] = 17704192
values[5] = 350
values[6] = 0
values[7] = 0
values[8] = 0
values[9] = 35
```

I'm using `cl arrays.c -o arrays` to compile.

Comment: If that is the exact code in the book, I would suggest finding a different book.

Comment: I tried to find an answer and found a response from a related topic after posting [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709392/odd-output-by-an-array?rq=1) I'll try to read more into it, if anyone got an answer anyway it'd be very helpful.

Comment: I have a feeling that values[10] was a global variable in the book. If not, I agree with hacks and crashmstr.

Comment: Ah. okay thanks. Do you find any error in the code?

Comment: @user3101661 there's no apparent error in the code -- the error is in the assumption that uninitialized values will be 0. They will be whatever they happen to be; it's system, compiler, and compiler switch dependent. If you don't set a variable that is defined within a function, it has _some_ value, but you have no guarantee of _what_ the value is in advance.

Comment: @user3101661; *Do you find any error in the code?*: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22618748/2455888).

Comment: Note that global variables are initialized to 0, local variables are not initialized. So if `values` is changed to a global variable, the code will work as expected.

Comment: i think that the book just wanted to show what happens when you use a for cycle over an array which you aren't sure that all locations contain something

Comment: @sscnapoli1926; Yes you are right. Read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22618981/2455888)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables are ***not*** initialized. That means the entries in the array that you do not explicitly initialize will contain indeterminate values (values that will be seen as random).

Actually, using uninitialized variables (or uninitialized entries of an array) is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: That explains a bit, i've compiled arrays up to [5] earlier in the program so that's why [0]-[5] is the problematic ones and the above "works". Thanks alot people!

Answer (score 2):

they're not initialized, so what you see in consolle output is what there was in the same memory locations

you may wonder why the first example gives '0' for each uninitialized value and "wierd numbers" in your implementation....maybe the first example was allocated into a memory area never used before, or maybe some compiler decides to set at 0x0000000 every memory register referred but not initialized

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the cod provided in the book it never sets the value of array entries 1 or 4. They are therefore undefined and could be any value. Some compilers may go ahead and initialize them to zero but this is not part of the C specification and should never be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

I read the text that explain this program in the book which clearly says that (pg no. 100):

> Because you never assigned values to five of the elements in the array—elements 1, 4, and 6 through 8—the values that are displayed for them are meaningless. Even though the program’s
>   output shows these values as zero, the value of any uninitialized variable or array element
>   is not defined. For this reason, no assumption should ever be made as to the value of an
>   uninitialized variable or array element.

And this is what standard says that the uninitialized automatic local variable invokes undefined behavior.